# Use mouse to emit events

Tags: aframe

I am using the  click-drag component (https://github.com/jesstelford/aframe-click-drag-component) to drag entity's across the screen, and this is done by the mouse (not the cursor that is fixed in the middle of the screen). My question is how can I emit an event by clicking on the entity with the mouse and not with the cursor. (I am trying to clone the enity i click on and moving that one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A-Frame's cursor component has a mouse mode.

`<a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">`